# Create breakout for small FPGA in BGA package

Tags: fpga, breakout, lattice

I'm going to buy a MachXO3 FPGA by Lattice, famous for the low cost, in order to create a bridge between an HDMI input and a MIPI DSI output for low cost/high res display.

Lattice lets you buy only the FPGA without the breakout ([link](http://www.latticestore.com/default.aspx?tabid=417&searchid=1&searchvalue=XO3%2a)) and I have no idea how to obtain a dev board (no one seems to produce something with the machxo3) or how to create it.

Is it reasonably possible to create a DIY PCB ([instructions?](http://www.latticesemi.com/~/media/Documents/ApplicationNotes/PT/PCBLayoutRecommendationsforBGAPackages.pdf?document_id=671)) or buy a breakout for the BGA package that seems to be a FBGA-256?

PS: I'm quite new in electronic development, and I'm not able to use any EDA software (yet).

Comment: forget about doing it at home, the soldering might be feasible but you will need a multi layer pcb and I don't think it's possible to DIY one of these

Comment: argh! in your opinion, is it possible to obtain a "standard" FBGA-256 breakout? or this solution is anything but standard?

Comment: I bet yes. You might want to design your whole pcb and let them also solder the fpga for you, you can then add connectors and other components. Designing a pcb for an FPGA is not exactly a trivial task anyway...

Comment: I was looking for something like [this](http://www.alpha-crucis.com/it/breakout-boards/1098-spartan-3e-breakout-board-3700386685958.html) without the core in the middle, and you've only to add the chip :D

Comment: "bga breakout board" on google provides some possible solutions...

Comment: I was thinking that the board would need at least some decoupling caps, is there a standard?

Comment: passerby: well, I looked on google but I can't find anything interesting. Can you make me an example of what you would choose in this case?

Comment: vladimir: well... I don't know really :)

Comment: I think the fpga datasheet provide a sample layout that includes decoup caps and whatever is absolutely needed to have it working properly.

Comment: @VladimirCravero I'm going to look at the docs... but still have no idea about how I can make it works

Comment: The parts seem to be pretty much imaginary at the moment, maybe an imaginary eval board would work for you?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It shouldn't be too much imaginary, new stocks will arrive in 13 weeks. But yes, eval board would be **super perfect**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since these parts are preliminary and are not really in distribution yet (you say 13 weeks or 1/4 year to get initial units).. you might want to contact Lattice sales and see if they plan to have eval boards available around the same time as actual parts.

[This](http://ca.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Lattice/LCMXO2-7000HE-B-EVN/?qs=DBbQ3l7BldNJuSVNFnSpPw==) eval board for the QFP144 LCMXO2 (Mach02) is sold for only $30, and chances are that even a more capable evaluation board will not be much more than $200. Having a multilayer board fabbed and BGA soldered to it will not be cheaper, even if you had the tools to create the Gerbers yourself, and there will be a lot of room for problems with tons of bypass capacitors, USB programming circuitry and so on.

Comment: Yes this would be perfect **if** the fpga supported DSI. Maybe it actually can. I'll probably contact Lattice. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

Since the comments are going too far I am giving my opinion here.

You should search for a commercial evaluation board with a device similar to your target, possibly with the HDMI connector already soldered. There is *a ton* of reasons behind my opinion, I am giving what comes to me from the top of my mind.

- This seem a one time project - no production, no board selling - designing a whole board just for that is a waste of time.
- You don't seem to have the know-how: an FPGA is a great, fast beast: it would need a lot of decoupling capacitors, you should put extra care in traces impedances, especially the HDMI ones, you should take care of a whole lot of things that you would encounter during the PCB design phase and possibly after the first prototype.
- You don't seem to have the appropriate hardware: soldering that package without a reflow oven is impossible, soldering the other components might be feasible but... Have you ever soldered even 3216 parts? (I **love** the SI).
- You don't really want to deal with all the other things that an FPGA needs to run properly: what about the clock? What about the programmer? What about power? These guys can draw quite a bit of current.
- I am pretty sure you can't do a multi layer PCB on your own... Nobody probably can anyway.

That said, your best option is to just buy an EVAL board and stick with it.